# Cordova run --debug building blank app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I've built an app with ionic. When I use phonegap desktop program to run it on a server and view it on my phone it displays the app correctly however when I run

```
ionic platform add android
ionic build android
platforms\android\cordova\run --debug
```

The app which launches is the plain cordova app with blinking `device is ready` and title `APACHE CORDOVA`.

This is really annoying since I don't understand what is happening and how could this even happen. I am building the correct solution but the installed apk is something totally different. I don't even have a view that dislays that in my project files!!!!

**EDIT** I just found something completely unexpected. In `platforms\android\assets\www` the files are the original cordova blank app (the view that I see in device) but in my app `www` folder the files are totally. My guess is that `cordova build android` is not really building the correct app. What could be the cause of this and how can I fix it?

**EDIT2**
If I copy my `~/www` content to `platforms\android\assets\www` then it will render the correct details. I'm still confused as to why cordova build does not copy the correct asset files to the relevant directory

**EDIT3** If anyone else is experiencing the same problem take note that cordova is not copying or compiling any of the files in `www` folders. That goes for the plugins too. In order to install plugins you must do:

```
cordova plugin add <plugin-name>
```

I am not aware of why this happens. It might be worth opening a ticket for the cordova team to fix this issue.

Comment: look at my suspect 2 in the answer below...You perhaps have a copy of that project.

Comment: I did none of them apply. I don't use any IDE and the config.xml points to the right file as running it through phonegap displays correct behavior. Please check my edit and see if you have any idea what might cause this

Comment: try running "$ cordova run android" from the root folder of your project.

Comment: I did try that it did not work. It doesn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

If it blinks device is ready that means that the project is set up correctly. You have index.html file in www folder which contains that "view". And in that index.html file you will see two divs with two classes, one of them has "blink". Now you can delete that lines and start coding :)

Comment: No my ~/www/index.html does not have that view it has a bunch of ionic views set up with angular-ui routes. I've just found some thing else

Answer (score 0):

I have two suspects:

1. Check your config.xml and point the src to your html file, default is index.html, which is the ready to print icon.
2. You might perhaps be editing your project using an IDE that would copy the files and create a physically different project than where cordova folder is. Like eclipse. If you create new project in eclipse and import, it could copy the cordova project into eclipse workspace (based on some options if not carefully done)..So any edits done on the project will not be available from where you are launching:

   platforms\android\cordova\run --debug

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. After digging around a bit, someone from the Ionic Forum suggested a workaround - downgrading Node to 4.2.2. It worked for me!