# Cordova Overriding Ionic - Application Gets Stuck at "Apache Cordova - Device Ready" Screen

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I was having some issues lately with my Node / NPM / Ionic installations, so removed everything and installed again.

Since then, I notice a weird behavior after I start new projects through Ionic CLI (v1.7.7) - by running *ionic start myApp blank*, for instance (I've already tried removing ios platform and adding again before building the project).

- Whenever I add the iOS platform, I noticed that the index.html file is not copied to the platforms/ios/www folder
- When I run the app on iPhone it gets stuck at the "Apache Cordova - Device Ready" screen (probably as a result from the previous);
- Splash screen shows Cordova logo, instead of Ionic one which used to be shown with my previous installation;
- Application icon also shows Cordova logo - used to show Ionic logo
  Cordova version is 5.3.3.

I'm running OS X Yosemite and my Node.JS version is 5.0.0.

Comment: FYI: Support for [Cordova for iOS9](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/11/02/cordova-ios-3.9.2.html) was released just a few days ago. Don't know if it will help.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem. I am on Mac OSX El Cap. I did everything you did, plus adding in homebrew (much easier on CLI see http://www.johnpapa.net/how-to-use-npm-global-without-sudo-on-osx/)

I was stuck till I tried this stackoverflow question:([Cordova run --debug building blank app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33488341/cordova-run-debug-building-blank-app)) where I found that I was having the same problem - ionic build is not copying the www folder over to the /platforms/ios/www folder. Once I copied this over it worked in the ios emulator.

I hope that helps till they fix it! What a pain! I like the platform - but not this error.

Comment: Do I need to configure anything after copying the folder? addition changes on the external files ?

Answer (score 0):

Someone from the Ionic Forum suggested downgrading Node to 4.2.2. It worked! :)